# spark - How to effectively remove rows from dataframe where all chosen columns contain nulls?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some `dataframe` with many columns and list of column names.
How to remove these rows that contains `nulls` in **all** column from list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.na.drop` and specify `all` and a sequence of column names. Then it will drop a row only if every specified column is null in that row.

```
val col_seq = Seq("col1", "col2").filter(df.columns.contains(_))
val df2 = if (col_seq.length > 0) df.na.drop("all", col_seq) else df
```

Comment: It looks nice. Is it possible to not drop when these columns does not exists in dataframe

Comment: @tomek.xyz you can add a check, as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a case when list of columns is empty. Does it exist any elegant approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

"*Remove rows which all columns from that list are null*" is equivalent to : "*Keep rows which at least one column from that list is not null*". Thus, you can use this last condition to filter the data frame:

```
val df1 = df.filter(colsList.map(col(_).isNotNull).reduce(_ or _))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` for remove `null` values for every column;

```scala
df.filter(r => !r.anyNull)
```